# How to calculate percentage with a SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table that contains users & their grades. For simplicity's sake, lets just say there are 2 columns - `name` & `grade`. So a typical row would be Name: "John Doe", Grade:"A".

I'm looking for one SQL statement that will find the percentages of all possible answers. (A, B, C, etc...) Also, is there a way to do this without defining all possible answers (open text field - users could enter 'pass/fail', 'none', etc...)

The final output I'm looking for is A: 5%, B: 15%, C: 40%, etc...

Answer (score 276, accepted):

I have tested the following and this does work. The answer by gordyii was close but had the multiplication of 100 in the wrong place and had some missing parenthesis.

```
Select Grade, (Count(Grade)* 100 / (Select Count(*) From MyTable)) as Score
From MyTable
Group By Grade
```

Comment: this gives result in integers .sum of results is not equal to 100.

Comment: Not the most efficient as the table will be scanned twice. Also the query will not look that simple if there is more than one table referenced.

Comment: @Thunder you can change 100 to 100.0 for decimal values.

Comment: Can someone explain why the mathematical syntax of the SQL query isn't what you'd expect to do normally? For example normal I would have divided by total then times by 100? Genuinely curious about this from a logical stand point.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt (100 * 2) / 4 = 50, (2/4) * 100 = 50 as long as the enumerator is is the part being multiplied.  Due to precedence of SQL statements it will be the same. however, due to data types if using 100 you can still get the result rounded to 0 decimals you desire for the % where as if you put it after the division operation you would have to make sure that you cast to a data type that can handle the decimal places otherwise you will end up with 100 or 0 and never an actual percentage

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the response, that makes sense, and I think the part about data types having to support decimals is what originally threw me off, because I wasn't contextualising the constraints of the data types in my thinking, so in my head it was all a bit strange.

Comment: the solution it's good but you have to take into account that the divisor could be 0 if the table is empty and that would throw an error

Comment: Somehow this solution didn't give the sum as 100 in the end. I tried changing to decimal values as well. Using @john-gibb 's answer returns 100. Not sure why

Answer (score 351):

1. The most efficient (using over()).

   ```
   select Grade, count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over()
   from MyTable
   group by Grade
   ```
2. Universal (any SQL version).

   ```
   select Grade, count(*) * 100.0 / (select count(*) from MyTable)
   from MyTable
   group by Grade;
   ```
3. With CTE, the least efficient.

   ```
   with t(Grade, GradeCount) 
   as 
   ( 
       select Grade, count(*) 
       from MyTable
       group by Grade
   )
   select Grade, GradeCount * 100.0/(select sum(GradeCount) from t)
   from t;
   ```

Comment: over() worked perfectly on my SQL Server 2008, I did the math to confirm.  In order to round it off to 2 decimal places I used CAST(count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over() AS DECIMAL(18, 2)). Thanks for the post!

Comment: In case you overflow on the 100 multiplication (e.g. _Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int_), replace it with division in denominator instead: `cast((count(*) / (sum(count(*)) over() / 100)) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) as Percentage`

Comment: @RJB Why do you have to multiply by 100.0 and not just 100 when you're casting the output as a decimal?

Comment: @AS91, because the cast to decimal happens AFTER the division operation. If you leave an int (100), dividing by another int will result in an int as well, which will round the result. That is why the trick is always to force a cast on the dividend before the actual division (you can either multiply by a literal decimal like 1.0 or cast/convert)

Comment: Option 1 with `over()` works great on Postgresql 10

Answer (score 50):

Instead of using a separate CTE to get the total, you can use a window function without the "partition by" clause.

If you are using:

```
count(*)
```

to get the count for a group, you can use:

```
sum(count(*)) over ()
```

to get the total count.

For example:

```
select Grade, 100. * count(*) / sum(count(*)) over ()
from table
group by Grade;
```

It tends to be faster in my experience, but I think it might internally use a temp table in some cases (I've seen "Worktable" when running with "set statistics io on").

**EDIT:**
I'm not sure if my example query is what you are looking for, I was just illustrating how the windowing functions work.

Comment: +1. This is great. It can also be used if in place of 'table' there is a select statement.

Comment: It uses a spool in `tempdb` which is the work table. The logical reads seem higher [but they are counted differently than normal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5194902/73226)

Comment: Actually, the `COUNT(*) OVER ()` in your query would return a completely unrelated figure (specifically, the number of rows of the *grouped* result set). You should use `SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()` instead.

Comment: brilliant John, i battle on this with chatgpt for a while now, i wish i could upvote more than once

Answer (score 24):

I simply use this when ever I need to work out a percentage..

```
ROUND(CAST((Numerator * 100.0 / Denominator) AS FLOAT), 2) AS Percentage
```

Note that 100.0 returns 1 decimal, whereas 100 on it's own will round up the result to the nearest whole number, even with the ROUND(...,2) function!

Answer (score 12):

You have to calculate the total of grades 
If it is SQL 2005 you can use CTE

```
    WITH Tot(Total) (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
    )
    SELECT Grade, COUNT(*) / Total * 100
--, CONVERT(VARCHAR, COUNT(*) / Total * 100) + '%'  -- With percentage sign
--, CONVERT(VARCHAR, ROUND(COUNT(*) / Total * 100, -2)) + '%'  -- With Round
    FROM table
    GROUP BY Grade
```

Comment: Of course, this only gives the percentages for grade codes present in the table, not for those that could be present and aren't.  But without a definitive list of the relevant (valid) grade codes, you can't do better.  Hence the +1 from me.

Comment: The hidden gem for me was you commented out CONVERT.

Answer (score 11):

You need to group on the grade field. This query should give you what your looking for in pretty much any database.

```
    Select Grade, CountofGrade / sum(CountofGrade) *100 
    from
    (
    Select Grade, Count(*) as CountofGrade
    From Grades
    Group By Grade) as sub
    Group by Grade
```

You should specify the system you're using.

Comment: Since you have an aggregate ('sum(CountofGrade)') in the outer select, don't you need a group by clause in it too?  And in standard SQL, I think you could use '/ (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Grades)' to get the grand total.

Comment: IBM Informix Dynamic Server doesn't like the naked SUM in the select-list (though it gives a somewhat less-than-helpful message when it complains).  As noted in my answer and prior comment, using a full sub-select expression in the select-list does work in IDS.

Comment: This is also better because one can apply complex where to inner query.

Answer (score 7):

The following should work

```
ID - Key
Grade - A,B,C,D...
```

EDIT:  Moved the `* 100` and added the `1.0` to ensure that it doesn't do integer division

```
Select 
   Grade, Count(ID) * 100.0 / ((Select Count(ID) From MyTable) * 1.0)
From MyTable
Group By Grade
```

Comment: this works, but the answers all come back as 0 - do I need to do some sort of number formatting or conversion to see the proper answer?

Comment: Select Grade, round(Count(grade) * 100.0 / ((Select Count(grade) From grades) * 1.0) ,2) From grades Group By Grade for adding a round function in sql-server returend eg : 21.56000000000

Answer (score 6):

This is, I believe, a general solution, though I tested it using IBM Informix Dynamic Server 11.50.FC3.  The following query:

```
SELECT grade,
       ROUND(100.0 * grade_sum / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM grades), 2) AS pct_of_grades
    FROM (SELECT grade, COUNT(*) AS grade_sum
            FROM grades
            GROUP BY grade
         )
    ORDER BY grade;
```

gives the following output on the test data shown below the horizontal rule.  The `ROUND` function may be DBMS-specific, but the rest (probably) is not.  (Note that I changed 100 to 100.0 to ensure that the calculation occurs using non-integer - DECIMAL, NUMERIC - arithmetic; see the comments, and thanks to Thunder.)

```
grade  pct_of_grades
CHAR(1) DECIMAL(32,2)
A       32.26
B       16.13
C       12.90
D       12.90
E       9.68
F       16.13
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE grades
(
    id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    grade CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK (grade MATCHES '[ABCDEF]')
);

INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1001', 'A');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1002', 'B');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1003', 'F');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1004', 'C');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1005', 'D');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1006', 'A');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1007', 'F');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1008', 'C');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1009', 'A');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1010', 'E');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1001', 'A');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1012', 'F');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1013', 'D');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1014', 'B');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1015', 'E');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1016', 'A');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1017', 'F');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1018', 'B');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1019', 'C');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1020', 'A');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1021', 'A');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1022', 'E');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1023', 'D');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1024', 'B');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1025', 'A');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1026', 'A');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1027', 'D');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1028', 'B');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1029', 'A');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1030', 'C');
INSERT INTO grades VALUES('1031', 'F');
```

Comment: gives integer percent in sql-server

Comment: @Thunder: interesting; what happens if you change, say, the 100 to 100.00?

Comment: Sure the result is in decimal with 100.0

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Grade, GradeCount / SUM(GradeCount)
FROM (SELECT Grade, COUNT(*) As GradeCount
      FROM myTable
      GROUP BY Grade) Grades
```

Answer (score 3):

In any sql server version you could use a variable for the total of all grades like this:

```
declare @countOfAll decimal(18, 4)
select @countOfAll = COUNT(*) from Grades

select
Grade,  COUNT(*) / @countOfAll * 100
from Grades
group by Grade
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a subselect in your from query (untested and not sure which is faster):

```
SELECT Grade, COUNT(*) / TotalRows
FROM (SELECT Grade, COUNT(*) As TotalRows
      FROM myTable) Grades
GROUP BY Grade, TotalRows
```

Or

```
SELECT Grade, SUM(PartialCount)
FROM (SELECT Grade, 1/COUNT(*) AS PartialCount
      FROM myTable) Grades
GROUP BY Grade
```

Or

```
SELECT Grade, GradeCount / SUM(GradeCount)
FROM (SELECT Grade, COUNT(*) As GradeCount
      FROM myTable
      GROUP BY Grade) Grades
```

You can also use a stored procedure (apologies for the Firebird syntax):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
INTO :TotalCount;

FOR SELECT Grade, COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Grade
INTO :Grade, :GradeCount
DO
BEGIN
    Percent = :GradeCount / :TotalCount;
    SUSPEND;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is working well in MS SQL. It transforms varchar to the result of two-decimal-places-limited float.

```
Select field1, cast(Try_convert(float,(Count(field2)* 100) / 
Try_convert(float, (Select Count(*) From table1))) as decimal(10,2)) as new_field_name 
From table1 
Group By field1, field2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this. you should be able to get the correct result multiplying by 1.0 instead of 100.See example Image attached

Select Grade, (Count(Grade)* 1.0 / (Select Count(*) From MyTable)) as Score From MyTable Group By Grade
[image: See reference image attached]

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors.