# SQL percents, revenue of a region by percent, confused

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, vba, aggregate

[How to calculate percentage with a SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770579/how-to-calculate-percentage-with-a-sql-statement/26951805#26951805)

I have a similar question to this except for revenue.
A corporation has a region (east west central) and a revenue

I've aggregated the regions but i'm having trouble dealing with the percents, this is what i have so far

- Summary of revenues by region (in ranked order from highest to lowest, calculate % of total for each region)

here's my code so far

```
SELECT Region, Sum(revenue) AS TotalRevenue
FROM Sales
GROUP BY Region
ORDER BY Sum(revenue) DESC;
```

i've also tried

```
SELECT Sales.Region, Sales.Sales.[*] AS Expr1
FROM Sales
GROUP BY Sales.Sales.[*], Sales;
```

i'm still very confused

I tried this code, and it worked
SELECT
  Region
  , Sum(revenue) AS TotalRevenue
  , Sum(revenue) / (SELECT SUM(revenue) FROM Sales) * 100 AS percentage
FROM Sales
GROUP BY Region
ORDER BY Sum(revenue) DESC;

Now, there's another part

For the region with the smallest revenue, show the products by revenue and % of regional sales
For the region with the smallest revenue, show the customers list ranked by revenue and % of regional sales
and then I have to prepare graphs or talbes to summarize my findings in excel
should i just copy and paste my data into excel or link it to excel/import it into excel? if i need to do that ,how would i do that?  thanks

Comment: What is `Sales.Sales.[*]` supposed to mean?

Comment: Please do not mangle the question.  In order to be useful to anyone else, you must preserve the question as it was when Abecee answered.  Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  Region
  , Sum(revenue) AS TotalRevenue
  , Sum(revenue) / (SELECT SUM(revenue) FROM Sales) * 100 percentage
FROM Sales
GROUP BY Region
ORDER BY Sum(revenue) DESC;
```

Comment: Where do you need the percent sign? Inside the column holding the value? This would require to change it to a character type - which would affect potential further processing.  
(SQL Fiddle did not complain about a missing `AS`, sorry.)

Comment: ABC, it's solved, can you remove your answer or make it a blank/something else and i can give you approval if you do that, otherwise i won't