# SQL Percentile function missing?

Tags: sql, oracle, function

It is a mystery to me with this text book example. We have simply:

```
Transaction_ID (primary key),   Client_ID,  Transaction_Amount, Month

1                   1       500         1   
2                   1       1000            1
3                   1       10          2
4                   2       11          2
5                   3       300         2
6                   3       10          2
...                 ...     ...         ...
```

I want to calculate in SQL the mean(Transaction_Amount), std(Transaction_Amount) and the some percentile(Transaction amount) grouped by Client_ID. But is seems, even given that percentile is a very similar calculation than the standard deviation, SQL cannot do it with a simple statement as:

```
SELECT
    mean(Transaction_Amount),
    std(Transaction_Amount),
    percentile(Transaction_Amount) 
FROM
    myTable
GROUP BY
    Client_ID, Month
```

Or can it?

It gets worse becuase I also need to Group By Month in addition to Client_ID.

Thanks a lot!
Sven

Comment: It depends a lot on the database.  Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What Gordon Lightfoot meant was, are you using SQL Server, or Oracle, or MongoDB, or MagicPlatypus, or what? If SQL Server, at least, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770579/how-to-calculate-percentage-with-a-sql-statement

Comment: Worse yet, there is more than one type of percentile.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile.  If the functionality of your database engine does not satisfy your business requirement, which has happened to me, you need a different plan.

Comment: I am foreced to use SAS proc sql.....trible I can tell you. And it is SAS BI Enterprise 5.1.

Comment: Any percentile (beeing it 1% or 99%) would be good because I can then adopt the procedure to all the other that I need.

Comment: But will double check and let you know what database it is. I think Oracle.

Comment: it is oracle, any help appreciated with the queery for, say ths 95% percentile.   @Gordon Linoff

Comment: I am pretty sure that `percentile` takes more than one argument

Comment: Are you looking for the [NTILE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions101.htm) function ?

Comment: First you say you use "*SAS proc SQL*", then you say it's Oracle. So what is it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure Oracle *can* do the calculations you want.  I just don't know what they are.  You specify that you want something grouped by `ClientId`.  Yet, your sample query has two keys in the `GROUP BY`.

Some functions that you want to look at are:

- `AVG()`
- `STDDEV()`
- `PERCENT_RANK()`

Without sample data and desired results (or a very clear explanation of what you are trying to calculate), I can't put together a query.