# Calculate percentage of several tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have several tables all of which have the column LOCQUALITY. There are about 10 different values for LOCQUALITY. I want to know the percentage of the LOCQUALITY field from all the tables combined. I have been using these two queries:

```
Select LOCQUALITY, (Count(LOCQUALITY)* 100 / (Select Count(*) From TSDBA.TS_LOCATION))
From TSDBA.TS_LOCATION
Group By LOCQUALITY
```

This one gets the percentage of just one table. I go it from here [How to calculate percentage with a SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770579/how-to-calculate-percentage-with-a-sql-statement)

And I used this one to determine which are the tables that have the LOCQUALITY column (It returned like 30 tables). Got it from here [Find all tables containing column with specified name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name)

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%LOCQUALITY%'
```

I want to combine these two but I have only gotten errors. Thanks for your help

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag because the syntax suggests MySQL.

Comment: you are going to do it by hand -- you can't pick which tables to select from in a select statement without dynamic sql.  But your percentage calculation does not make sense.