# Perform arithmetic in SQL

Tags: sql

could you please help me with this? I have the following query which returns country name, number of records for each country, and total number of countries . How can I get it to also return a column for % of each country with respect to total number. Ideal output would be something like.

> USA, 25, 100, 25% ... UK, 28, 100, 28% ... etc...

```
SELECT Country, COUNT(Country) AS number, (SELECT COUNT(Country) 
FROM[Customers]) AS total FROM [Customers] 
GROUP BY Country ORDER BY number DESC
```

I have tried `number/total AS percent` but it didn't work. Obviously I am doing something wrong.

I want to be able to filter countries that are above certain percentage say 20%.

Thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770579/how-to-calculate-percentage-with-a-sql-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a derived table, which is a subquery with an alias.

```
select number/total AS percent 
from (
your query goes here
) derivedTable
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I just had to multiply "number" by 100 to get the percent like 5, 12, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it manually :

```
SELECT Country, COUNT(Country)*100/ (SELECT COUNT(Country) FROM[Customers]) AS total FROM [Customers] where total >20
```

Answer (score 0):

Below SQL would help you.

```
SELECT Country, COUNT(Country) AS number, (SELECT COUNT(Country) FROM[Customers]) AS total, ROUND(COUNT(Country) * 100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(Country) FROM[Customers]), 1) FROM [Customers]
```