# SQL Query calculation across tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, percentage

I have 3 tables that are joined using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    b.[_PRESS_INST_NO]
    ,a.[X_PO_NO]
    ,a.[X_GOODS_CD]
    ,a.[X_QTY]
    ,c.RM_CD
    ,c.RM_QTY
FROM 
    T1 a
    INNER JOIN T2 b ON a.X_PO_NO=b.X_PO_NO
    INNER JOIN T3 c ON b._PRESS_INST_NO=c.[_PRESS_INST_NO]
```

[image]

My desired result is `RM_QTYPerUnit` that can be done by Excel formula:

```
RM_QTYPerUnit = X_QTY * RM_QTY / SUM(X_QTY)
```

Total RM_QTY of X_PO_NO: VG00181 is 2320, and RM_QTY for X_GOODS_CD : 332034960 is 1094.34 not 2320.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? Here are some examples of percent of base calculations in SQL: http://sqlusa.com/bestpractices/percentonbase/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770579/how-to-calculate-percentage-with-a-sql-statement. Have a go although I'm sure someone will soon post a solution for you.

Comment: SQL Server 2008

Comment: The formula says `SUM(X_QTY)`. Is it the SUM of the whole table?

Comment: SUM(X_QTY) is only sum column T1 of X_PO_NO: VG00181 only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need `SUM` partitioned by `X_PO_NO`. It is easy to get using the `OVER` clause:

```
SELECT 
    b.[_PRESS_INST_NO]
    ,a.[X_PO_NO]
    ,a.[X_GOODS_CD]
    ,a.[X_QTY]
    ,c.RM_CD
    ,c.RM_QTY
    ,a.[X_QTY] * c.RM_QTY / 
    SUM(CAST(a.[X_QTY] AS float)) OVER (PARTITION BY a.X_PO_NO) AS RM_QTYPerUnit
FROM 
    T1 a
    INNER JOIN T2 b ON a.X_PO_NO=b.X_PO_NO
    INNER JOIN T3 c ON b._PRESS_INST_NO=c.[_PRESS_INST_NO]
;
```

If the `X_QTY` values are so large that their sum doesn't fit into 4-byte `int`, then cast them to `float` or `decimal` with appropriate scale and precision.

Comment: Error: An arithmetic overflow error occurred while converting expression to data type int.

Comment: @user3035133, if the `X_QTY` values are so large that their sum doesn't fit into 4-byte `int`, then cast them to `float` or `decimal` with appropriate scale and precision. I updated the answer.

Comment: How to cast this one to Decimal : SUM(a.[X_QTY]) OVER (PARTITION BY a.X_PO_NO) AS RM_QTYPerUnit

Comment: @user3035133, you need to decide what scale and precision are appropriate in your case. The syntax is the same as shown in the answer: `SUM(CAST(a.[X_QTY] AS decimal(38,2) )) OVER (...)`

Comment: OK! I got it . But my result is  1094.339622  I just need 1094.34. Thank a lot Vladimir Baranov

Comment: @user3035133, normally you should round the result on the client as you display it to the end user. If you really want to do it on the server, there is [`ROUND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql) function.