# Calculating a percentage from database with sql query(SQL Management studio 2012)?

Tags: sql

Using SQL Management studio 2012

I have a query similar to below but need to add the percentage column of the pass rate

```
SELECT 

pass,
fail,
total,
name

FROM table


pass  fail total  name     %
 3      1    4    Joe      75
 5      0    5     Matt    100
 1      1    2     Al      50
 7      0    7    Freda    100
```

What I've tried to get the result:

```
SELECT

name,
sum(pass) /Sum(total) *100.0 as pass_rate


FROM
(
SELECT 

pass,
fail,
total,
name

FROM table
)a

GROUP BY name
```

Result obtained when running above query(which is wrong):

```
name    pass_rate

 Joe      100
 Matt     100
 Al        0
 Freda    100
```

Please help. Thankyou.

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770579/how-to-calculate-percentage-with-a-sql-statement

Comment: Just move that Multiply by 100 inside to numerator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move that Multiply by 100 inside to numerator

```
SELECT
name,
SUM(pass) * 100 /Sum(total) AS pass_rate
....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a93be2a4ff15b5efb856122c4b878be2)**

```
select 
pass,
fail,
total,
name,(pass*1.0/total)*100 as pass_rate
from table
```

OUTPUT:

```
  pass  fail    total   name    pass_rate
    3        1       4       Joe    75.0
    5        0       5       Matt   100.0
    1        1       2       Al     50.0
    7        0       7       Freda  100.0
```