# Calculate percentage aggregating counts in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table called `AccessLog` that is inserted into every time a user clicks "Log In" on my website. The important fields are `UserID`, `BrowserName` and `Date`. The intent is to get an idea of which browsers are used the most to access the site.

Here is a sample data set:

```
| UserID | BrowserName | Date  |
|--------|-------------|-------|
| 1      | Chrome      | 05/28 |
| 1      | Chrome      | 05/29 |
| 2      | Firefox     | 05/29 |
| 1      | Chrome      | 05/30 |
| 3      | Firefox     | 05/31 |
```

This is the SQL code I use (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770579/how-to-calculate-percentage-with-a-sql-statement)):

```sql
SELECT BrowserName
    ,(COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()) pct
    ,COUNT(*) ct
FROM AccessLog
GROUP BY BrowserName
```

These are the results I get with that query:

```
| BrowserName | pct  | ct |
|-------------|------|----|
| Chrome      | 60.0 | 3  |
| Firefox     | 40.0 | 2  |
```

But these are the results I want:

```
| BrowserName | pct  | ct |
|-------------|------|----|
| Chrome      | 33.3 | 1  |
| Firefox     | 66.6 | 2  |
```

How can I modify my query to count each distinct `UserID` and `BrowserName` pair once, to not artificially inflate the counts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following by creating a `cte`. Here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aea2502ff74416bba48c79d064adf215).

```
with total_users as
(
    select
      BrowserName,
      count(distinct UserId) as total_users
    from myTable
    group by
      BrowserName
)    
select 
    BrowserName,
    round((total_users * 100.0)/sum(total_users) over (), 1) as pct,
    total_users as ct
from total_users
```

Output:

```
| browsername | pct   | ct  |
| ----------- | ----- | --- |
| Chrome      | 33.3  | 1   |
| Firefox     | 66.6  | 2   |
```

Comment: This is perfect - I cast the pct column to a decimal to remove the extra 0's, but otherwise perfect. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `count(distinct)`.  But that is not possible as a window function -- directly -- in SQL Server.  So use the `dense_rank()` trick:

```
SELECT BrowserName,
       (COUNT(DISTINCT UserId) * 100.0 /
        (DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY UserId ASC) +
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY UserId DESC)
        )
       ) as pct,
      COUNT(DISTINCT UserId) as ct
FROM AccessLog
GROUP BY BrowserName
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got syntax errors from this in the lines beginning with SUM and COUNT. My best guess edit to remove those returned `Column 'AccessLog.UserId` is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` I added `UserId` to the `GROUP BY` clause and got `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.`

Comment: @aswans2012 . . . That line was detritus.  I thought I had deleted it.

Comment: Still getting `Column 'AccessLog.UserId' is invalid in the select list...` etc.

Comment: @aswans2012 . . . That column is in your sample data.