# SQL query to get percentages within a grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I've looked over similar questions and I just can't seem to get this right.

I have a table with three columns: ID, Date, and Method. None are unique.

I want to be able to see for any given date, how many rows match a certain pattern on Method.

So, for example, if the table has 100 rows, and 8 of them have the date "01-01-2020" and of those 8, two of them have a method of "A", I would want a return row that says "01-01-2020", "8", "2", and "25%".

My SQL is pretty rudimentary. I have been able to make a query to get me the count of each method by date:

select `Date`, count(*) from mytable WHERE `Method`="A" group by `Date`;

But I haven't been able to figure out how to put together the results that I am needing. Can someone help me out?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: In order to get count for every method + date - you'll need to add the Method field to the group by and select clauses,
In order to get the percentage of each method+date out of the total - you can use the following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770579/how-to-calculate-percentage-with-a-sql-statement

select Date, Method, count(*) from mytable WHERE Method="A" group by Date, Method;

Answer (score 0):

You could perform a `count` over a `case` expression for that method, and then divide the two counts:

```sql
SELECT   date,
         COUNT(*),
         COUNT(CASE method WHEN 'A' THEN 1 END),
         COUNT(CASE method WHEN 'A' THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) * 100
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're interested in all methods rather than just 'A', so you could do the following:

```
with ptotals as
(
    SELECT   
        thedate,
        count(*) as NumRows
    FROM     
        mytable
    group by
        thedate
)

select
    mytable.thedate,
    mytable.themethod,
    count(*) as method_count,
    100 * count(*) / max(ptotals.NumRows) as Pct 
from
    mytable
inner join
    ptotals
on
    mytable.thedate = ptotals.thedate
group by
    mytable.thedate,
    mytable.themethod
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AVG()` for the ratio/percentage:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(*),
       SUM(CASE WHEN method = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       AVG(CASE WHEN method = 'A' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0 END)
FROM  t
GROUP BY date;
```

Comment: The odd alias might be nice too