# Calculating a proportion using SQLite3

Tags: sqlite, average

I have a problem to solve where I need to calculate a proportion in SQL (to two decimals). I have a column of ids, and I need the proportion of these ids that meet a certain criteria (WHERE...). It's been a while since I've worked with SQL, so I was curious if anyone could give some general advice. Thank you!

Comment: I think you'll find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770579/how-to-calculate-percentage-with-a-sql-statement. Also, SO rewards posting your research, thoughts, attempts, and code, so consider adding that to your next question.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Since this was a homework question I wanted to keep it high level, but I understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the ratio of the `id`s that meet a condition like:

```
id > 100
```

or:

```
id > 100 AND id < 1000
```

or any other condition, you can use the condition directly inside the `AVG()` aggregate function:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(ID > 100), 2)
FROM tablename
```

or:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(ID > 100 AND id < 1000), 2)
FROM tablename
```

because SQLite evaluates the boolean expressions as `1` (true) or `0` (false).

This will return a floating point number between `0` and `1`.

If you want the result as a percentage you can multiply by `100`.