# How to find proportion of values in SQLite table that satisfy multiple conditions

Tags: python, sqlite

I am working with a practice SQlite3 table (gradebook) to learn more about them and it is set up with the following 3 columns

```
gradebook
   * student_id
   * student_name
   * test_score
```

I am trying to write a command that can help me find the % of students who scored over a certain score (0-100) on an exam and have a certain last name.

I was trying to follow this link,

[How to calculate percentage with a SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770579/how-to-calculate-percentage-with-a-sql-statement)

but I don't have enough understanding to generalize the equation. Was looking for some guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to piece it together. For a score threshold of 75 and last name of Smith:

```
100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gradebook) * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gradebook WHERE test_score > 75 AND student_name LIKE '%Smith%')
```

Where `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gradebook) gives the total number of students`,
and `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gradebook WHERE test_score > 75 AND student_name LIKE '%Smith%'`
gives the total number of students who scored above 75 and had the name 'Smith' present.