# Avarage of json array values in mysql

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I have `label` - its array of strings value (mysql `json` type) like: `["foo", "bar"]` and I would like to get avarage for those values like:
Example 1

```
ID | LABEL
1  | ["foo"]
2  | ["foo"]
3  | ["foo"]
4  | ["foo"]
```

Output: `foo`: 100%

Example 2

```
ID | LABEL
1  | ["foo"]
2  | ["foo"]
3  | ["bar"]
4  | ["bar"]
```

Output: `foo`: 50%
Output: `bar`: 50%

Example 3

```
ID | LABEL
1  | ["foo", "bar"]
2  | ["foo", "bar"]
```

Output: `foo`: 50%
Output: `bar`: 50%

How can I do it with single sql?

its possible?

I don't know which code should I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First what you need to do is to convert the items from the JSON array to rows.

You can do that with the [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) MySQL function:

```
SELECT *
FROM json_table('["foo", "bar"]', '$[*]' COLUMNS(item text PATH '$')) AS jt;
```

The resultset looks like the following:

```
+------+
| item |
+------+
| foo  |
| bar  |
+------+
```

The next problem is to [calculate the distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5846102/221213) of these values from the resultset.

```
SELECT item,
       count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) OVER () AS percentage
FROM json_table('["foo", "bar"]', '$[*]' COLUMNS(item text PATH '$')) AS jt
GROUP BY item;
```

The resultset will look like this:

```
+------+------------+
| item | percentage |
+------+------------+
| bar  |   50.00000 |
| foo  |   50.00000 |
+------+------------+
```

The final step is to join with the table:

```
SELECT item,
       count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) OVER () AS percentage
FROM your_table,
     json_table(label, '$[*]' COLUMNS(item text PATH '$')) AS jt
GROUP BY item;
```

And the result should be what you expected.