# SQL : count percent of each values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `Orders`, [column and values of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBZLJ.png).

Column `[Order Priority]` can have one of 4 values: Critical, High, Medium, Low. `Ship_tt` can have one of 3 values: Som, Tre, Dung.

I want to calculate percentage 'Som','Tre','Dung' of Critical, High, Medium, Low.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text.

Comment: And please show us your desired results.

Comment: Check out this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770579/how-to-calculate-percentage-with-a-sql-statement

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ORDER_PRIORITY, 100. * COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()
FROM @T T
GROUP BY ORDER_PRIORITY
```