# How can i fix this simple math query?

Tags: sql, math, percentage

i am trying to calculate the fat percentage from my data but I cannot get the query to work.
The equation should be. " Fat * 9, then that result divided by calories and then that result * by 100.
At the moment I have this but I cannot my result is always 0:

```
SELECT name, mfr, protein, calories, fat, (fat * 9 / calories) * 100   AS 'Fat Percentage'
 FROM cereals WHERE mfr IN ('K', 'G')
```

Comment: Integer division? Try `fat * 9.0` and see what happens.

Comment: What is your column Type for `fat`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate percentage with a SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770579/how-to-calculate-percentage-with-a-sql-statement)

Comment: The datatypes are Integers. 
By adding new brackets and changing 9 to 9.0 it ia now giving me good results. 

Thanks

    ((fat * 9.0) / calories) * 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put an extra bracket, it will work as per your requirement.

Use the following code:

```
SELECT name, mfr, protein, calories, fat, ((fat * 9) / calories) * 100   AS 'Fat Percentage'
FROM cereals WHERE mfr IN ('K', 'G');
```

Even though, if it doesn't work. Please, mention the datatype of the 'calories', 'fat' used in the table.

Comment: The datatypes are Integers. 
By adding new brackets and changing 9 to 9.0 it ia now giving me good results. 

Thanks

    ((fat * 9.0) / calories) * 100