# How do I calculate the percentage in SQL

Tags: sql, percentage

I am trying to calculate the percentage of the data that falls into categories.  I used this query:

```
select 
    distinct(city), 
    count(distinct id) over (partition by city) as CountofGoogle
from 
  TABLE  "
where 
    company_name = 'Google' 
order by 2 desc
```

I then ended up with these results:

| city | CountofGoogle |
| --- | --- |
| City A | 25000 |
| City B | 6000 |

(obv a more extended table)

I'm at a loss as to how I create a 3rd column that will give me a % of the  total?  (i.e. if there was a total of 100000  then city A would be 25%. I've tried sum etc but getting errors

Thanks

Comment: You're not the first one asking this, see for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770579/how-to-calculate-percentage-with-a-sql-statement (I know, the linked question is taged as SQLServer DB, but that's not really Db-type-specific)

Comment: `count(distinct id) over (partition by city) * 100  / count(distinct id) over () `