# Update SQL Table w/ Percentages

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with an id, a total count, and a specific code type count. I am trying to write a SQL statement that will go through and update each row with the percentage for the code type off the total count.

```
id     total_count      specific_code_count        percentage
1          27                   2                      ?
2          192                  101                    ?
3          99                   55                     ?
```

I am a bit of a novice and am struggling with figuring out the syntax to do this sort of thing. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you mean for example that you need to calculate what percentage `2` is of `27`?  And what percentage `101` is of `192`?  Do you know how to calculate that?  Though, taking a step back, *why* would this need to be stored in the table and not simply calculated any time it's needed?

Comment: You also need to _specify_ the expected result. We don't know which percentage you want.

Comment: `update t set percentage = specific_code_count * 1.0 / total_count from yourtable t`. If you want in percent, you can do: * 100.0 instead

Comment: create a view instead of storing calculated values. Will always be up-to-date!

Comment: Or a calculated column even. `alter table drop column percentage; alter table add percentage as specific_code_count * 1.0 / total_count`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate percentage with a SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770579/how-to-calculate-percentage-with-a-sql-statement)

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, you should avoid storing data that can easily be calculated from other columns.
If you really must use the calculated data, consider using a view or a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql) for it.

If the computation of the data is deterministic (meaning for a given set of values will always produce the same result), you can mark it as [persisted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql#persisted), which means that the SQL Server will store the data instead of compute it on demand.

A computed column can be indexed if it meets certain requirements, see [Indexes on computed columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns) for details, this means it is actually persisted in that index even if not marked as persisted.

This can be useful when you want to search the table based on a computed value - in this case, based on your `percentage` column.

Here's an example on how you can add percentage as a persisted computed column to an existing table:

```
-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1),
    total_count int,
    specific_code_count int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- Add percentage computed column
ALTER TABLE MyTable
    ADD [percentage] AS (total_count * 100.0 / specific_code_count) PERSISTED;
```